# Google Maps on multiple jQuery mobile pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maps

I am having a problem displaying my google maps on multiple pages within my jQuery mobile app. I have a list of 'jobs' and for every 'job' there is assoicated job information. The job information is an appended page and done so by a unique jobID as seen below. I want to add a map of the 'job' location to each appended page. I think the issue might be that I have to change the id = 'map' in the my google maps function. Any help would be appteciated in order to get each map on each page for each job.

Google Maps Code -

```
         <script>
              // Initialize and add the map
               function initMap() {
              // The location of the school
              var colaisteChiarain = {lat: 53.3641, lng: -6.4989};
              // The map, centered at Uluru
              var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 16, 
                center: colaisteChiarain,
                zoomControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                fullscreenControl: false,
                  });
             // The marker, positioned at Uluru

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: 
  colaisteChiarain, map: map});
        }
            </script>
            <!--Load the API from the specified URL
            * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page 
  while the API loads
            * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is 
  not needed for this tutorial)
            * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
            -->
            <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
 key=AIzaSyCOVjM5TbQis074pESLRehc3PpNBE1sll4&callback=initMap">
            </script>
```

Appended jQuery Page -

```
 $("#main_body").append('<div data-role="page" id='+ 
 jobpost.jobID+'>\n\
       <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">\n\
          <a href="#page4" class="ui-btn-left" 
    data-icon="user"\n\>Profile</a>EduSub Teacher\n\
     </div>\n\
          <div role="main" 
               id="content">\n\
                                       \n\<div id="map"></div>\n\
                                     <div class="schoolDetails">\n\
                                        <h1>'+ jobpost.title+' 
   Wanted</h1>\n\
                                        <h2><b>Date: </b>'+ 
   jobpost.dateFrom+' </b><b>to </b>'+ jobpost.dateTo+'<br>\n\
                                        <br><br>\n\
                                        <b>Location: </b>'+ 
   jobpost.location+'<br>\n\
                                        <br><br>\n\
                                        <b>Description: </b>'+ 
   jobpost.description+'<br>\n\
                                        </h2>\n\
                                        </div>  \n\
                                    </div>\n\
```

Comment: Does only one map show at any given time? Or are multiple maps appended to the page? How is the data for each location structured (e.g. latitude/longitude, address, etc.)?

Comment: Right now, no maps will show! 

Each page I would like to have a map appended to it. Each map will show the co-ordinates that I will retrieve from database.